# Is it possible to use selenium / webdriver in C# to test file drag and drop in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I've got a page on website that is using the awesome drag and drop file script http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload to handle FireFox and Chrome drag and drop file uploads.
Our team is trying to have integration tests for all the overall functionality of the sight using selenium. I don't see if there is a way in selenium to do this kind of functionality testing, or even fake it. Is there a way to do this in Selenium (or even another web testing automater?), or even a reasonable way to "fake" having the file drop down?
Edit:
For clarification - I'm not trying to drag things inside the browser to drop. I'm dragging files from outside the browser onto a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

Selenium can only interact with things rendered inside the browser.  It cannot interact with OS level things (e.g. OS pop up dialogue boxes, OS Windows like file explorer, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#tips-and-tricks ?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the drag and drop mentioned there. That is for dragging elements in the browser to other elements in the browser. I'm dragging files from windows explorer onto an area of the browser.